# CSS Position Div Over Another Div

Tags: css

I have two divs that I am trying to stack over each other but the one I want on top is not showing. I want the blue background div to lay on top of the red background div. Any advice? The reason why I want to overlay the blue div is because the container is a centered grid and I want the red div to be the background for the first half of the page.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kt77cp3e/2/)

### CSS

```
.buddy {
    width: 50%;
    height: 629px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
background: red;
  }

  .buddy-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: -629px;
    z-index: 10;
background: blue;
  }
 .container {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    padding: 0 10px;}
```

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kt77cp3e/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can update your code like this, it may solve the issue:

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/kt77cp3e/7/

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%:
}
.container {
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
}
.container>div {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
.container>div:first-child {
    top:0;
    height:50%;
    background:blue
}
.container>div:last-child {
    bottom:0;
    height:50%;
    background:green
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

**Update**: Considering the latest updated code, I think you should remove `overflow:hidden` from the container styles. That should do the trick

You should set the dimension on the `.container` div.
CSS:

```
.container {
    position:relative;
    width:100px; //You may modify these values
    height:100px
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kt77cp3e/1/

Comment: I added what the current container styles are. It a relative grid that is centered on the page. Sorry for not adding it initially.

Comment: @RyanSalmons Check now.

Comment: removing the overflow causes all the child elements on other pages to goof. Is there any other way? The goal is to have a background image that is half 1 color and the other half a different color while still utilizing the grid container's flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You have made the second div absolute so you don't need to give the negative value for top. The second div is hiding because you top -629px; Try making the top:0 and see. And also for your current code. Remove the overflow hidden and put z-index like this:

```
.buddy {
        width: 50%;
        height: 629px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
     z-index:9;
    background: red;
      }

      .buddy-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: -629px;
        z-index: 10;
    background: blue;
      }
.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
  position:relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.buddy {
        width: 50%;
        height: 629px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
    background: red;
      }
      
      .buddy-content {
        position: absolute;
        
        z-index: 10;
    background: blue;
      }
```

```html
<div class="buddy BlueGradient">
  &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="buddy-content">
  ROGER
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kt77cp3e/6/

just add z-index : higher to the div that you want to show on top and set z-index low to the other one ..

ant one thing your code is working good just you need to remove " top : -629px;"
that thing is not allowing blue div to be on top just it is showing at the -629 px position..!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
.buddy { width: 50%; height: 629px; display: inline-block; position: relative; background: red;}
.buddy-content { position: absolute; top: 0px; z-index: 10; background: blue; }
.container {max-width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; overflow:hidden; position:relative; padding: 0 10px;  position: relative;}


<div class="container">
    <div class="buddy BlueGradient">&nbsp;
        <div class="buddy-content">ROGER</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This brings the text "Roger" with blue background on top of the red background